# Does making a pdf searchable make it more vulnerable?

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

I would like to know if making a pdf 'searchable' somehow make it less secure?

Comment: While I don't know the answer in the absolute sense, I have met people who would think that it does, fundamentally speaking, because it gives people better access to the information that the pdf contains.  These people tend to see any form of disclosure as an information leak.  I'm still not entirely sure what the best way to deal with such people is.  They tend to put up a lot of barriers to geting anything accomplished, so that can be very frustrating.  This question might be better suited for https://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: this is opinion based. How do you define less secure ? secure to who ? less than what ? Define searchable ? from where ? with what ? etc.  - there's no way to answer this.